# how to write complex mathematics formula here?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

**How can i write math formula here**?there is any way to write **complex math formula** here?
**I want to add math equation here but it seems no tool for writing formula.**

Comment: Learn some *LaTeX*.

Comment: how to LateX here?

Comment: thanks to both of u....i'm trying to learn LaTeX..

Comment: For a beginner, some online equation editor might be useful, see this question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/latex-editor-suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [**This**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Also [**This**](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)

$\LaTeX$ are faster, efficient, beautiful and what not! Thanks to Knuth and others. (30 Chars+)

Oh! You can click edit to view posts by others and view the Latex coding.

Comment: thanks a lot dude.

Comment: +1 for how to view LaTeX coding.

Comment: You can also just right-click on the math and choose Show Math As > TeX Commands. This also works if you don't have edit privileges.